# MERN how to check login connecting Node, React, and database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm building a MERN application. I've successfully sent information from my Register component to the database, so all good there. Now I'm trying to check the user's username and password from the Login component against the database.

In the code below from my Node file, I get back what I want in the form of either the user's username and password or null; the information that I need is successfully in the console.log(). What I want to do now is get that information to my frontend, so that I can either put a message on the login page that says that the login was unsuccessful or I can confirm that it was successful and keep the username and database reference in order to allow the user to start liking posts, et cetera.

So basically, how do I get the data from my information variable below up to my frontend Login component where the user has entered and sent their username and password?

What I've tried: I've used trial and error to try to get this data up to frontend but without success. In tutorials and websites, they often start talking about JWT, sessions, cookies, et cetera, but for now I'm trying to understand things at a more basic level before moving forward, meaning the question that I asked above. Thank you for your time and patience.

The code from the API:

```
application.get('/check', async (request, response) => {
    const information = await db.collection('data').findOne({
            name: request.body.username,
            password: request.body.password,
    });
    console.log(information);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to send a response back so ...

```
response.json(information)
```

I recommend reading up on express documentation. [Express Request Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json)